# Clarification: Difference between \draw and \addplot?

Tags: pgfplots

In below example, I get a different behavior when using /draw by itself or in conjunction with `\addplot`.
In the former case the axis label changes (which I don't want) and the plot does not show. 
In the latter case, when the \addplot coordinate line is activated, the plot behaves as I intended (no axis label, showing all three plots).

Why does that happen?

```
   % Basierend auf einer Vorlage von: Author: Urs Zellweger (urs@zellweger.li),s. http://texample.net/tikz/examples/phasor-diagram/
    % Mit Hilfe von tex.stackexchange.com https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398784/coordinate-system-all-set-up-how-to-fill-it-now

    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations, arrows}

    \pgfplotsset{Diagram/.style={
                axis lines = left,
        xmax=9.5,
        ymax=1.5,
        xlabel = {$t$},
        xlabel style={at={(1,0)},anchor=west},
        ylabel style={at={(0,1)},rotate={-90},anchor=north east},
        ytick=\empty,
        no marks,
        every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, red},
                        }% end of Diagram style
                }% end of pgfplotsset

    %-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
    \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%% Diagramme f. 4TPPC %%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{figure}          
    \pgfplotsset{xticklabels={ , , $DT$, $T/2$, , $T$}, 
                              height=4cm, width=0.8\textwidth}        
    \centering            
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]

\begin{axis}[Diagram,ylabel = $i_L$]
\addplot coordinates {(0,.4)  (2,.7)  (4,.4)  (6,.7) (8,.4) (9,.7)};
\draw [ultra thin, blue] (0,.7) --++ (9,0) ;
\draw [ultra thin, blue] (0,.4) --++ (9,0) ;   
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{figure}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%        
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot` is a pgfplots command and does a lot of things to adjust axes etc. `\draw` is a native TikZ command and just draws at the given coordinates. If the coordinates are not visible at the current axis limits then you don't see anything.

Comment: I edited my example a bit. Any explanation why it looks the way it does? I've rather expected two horizontal blue lines at y=0.4 and y=0.7 and a zick zack in between these limits.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323480/relative-polar-coordinates-for-tikz-elements-in-axis-environment

Comment: Thanks, changed to absolute coordination and specified ymin=0, so my axis wouldn't move.